# If all ports are closed except for port 5001 and all internet traffic is blocked except for traffic to/from 1 remote server, can we still be hacked?

Tags: firewalls

We have closed all ports via our hardware firewall except for port 5001 which is open to allow our trading platform software (which does not have any publicly known software vulnerabilities) to communicate with our forex broker's trading server.  Via our firewall all internet traffic is blocked except for internet traffic to/from 1 remote server which belongs to our forex broker. Via the content filter on our firewall all websites are blocked except for the forex brokers website, so all users can not surf the internet.

We do our operating system updates manually.

Given the above setup, is it possible for a hacker to gain remote access to our computer if they somehow got hold of our IP address, if yes, how could a hacker gain access?  What hacking method could be used?

Comment: Social engineering.  e.g. phishing, dropped USB stick etc.  to get into your network via other route.

Comment: Our PC is in a data center in a co-location locked rack so no person has physical access to my PC except for me.  Could we still be hacked and therefore someone steal our sensitive files if they had our IP address?  If so, what method could they use?

Comment: Can the broker's trading server initiate connections to your server? How do you configure your hardware firewall? Is your server and network infrastructure bare metal or cloud based (i.e. virtualized/software defined)? And, on the OS updates, what do you mean that you do them manually? Can you please provide an example?